# sql-query to get report consisting of count of transactions

Tags: mysql, sql, join, report

i am kind of new to sql and i am lost for last two days

[image: this file shows the input table].

I need to create daily report using  MySQL of this table which contains the number of incoming and outgoing messages for each message identifiers of each institution (amazon )like shown in second image. I tried natural join,union none of them works correctly.

[image: second image]

Comment: where do the incoming outgoing come from thin air?

Comment: is it count of input/output ?

Comment: yes its the count of input and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you started.

```
set @a=0; 
select @a:=@a+1 serial_number,t.* 
from
 (Select institution as sender
           ,service
           ,`message identifier`
           ,`date`
           ,sum(case when subformat = 'INPUT' then 1 else 0 end) as Incoming
           ,sum(case when subformat = 'OUTPUT' then 1 else 0 end) as Outgoing
      from MyTable
      Group by
           institution
           ,service
           ,`message identifier`
           ,`date`) t ;
```

Comment: @ SHANIL t s - Let me know if this worked for you or not.

Comment: thanks ,i think it worked as expected but had an error group by institution as sender. but replacing it with group by institution .worked , does it have any impact on result

Comment: @ SHANIL t s - Nope, you are good. I actually realized it as well and edited to remove the “as” in the group by. It was a typo at my end. Please see my edited answer above.